# unable to connect to the server: eof in kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, devops, kubectl

I have followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/justmeandopensource/kubernetes/tree/master/kubeadm-ha-keepalived-haproxy/external-keepalived-haproxy) to create a 2 master 2 load balancer 1 worker kubernetes cluster, everything seemed to be working fine and I got my dashboard running. Up until I was trying to test the high availability and shut down one of the two masters, then I only get when I try any kubectl command

> Unable to connect to the server: EOF

Any idea what's wrong?

I am using ubuntu 20.04 as the main OS, and also ubuntu 20.04 for my VMs

Comment: Update: I logged to my loadbalancer and found this error `Mar 03 10:48:34 loadbalancer1 haproxy[2775]: [ALERT] 061/104834 (2775) : backend 'kubernetes-backend' has no server available!`

Comment: I hope this link will help you :
https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/unable-to-connect-to-the-server-eof-error-during-kubectl-command/23849

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already fixed your problem.

I've had a problem like this before. When I examined the problem, it was related to the firewall settings of the operating system I was using.

When I rebooted the server, my iptables rule filters were cleared, so the ports Kubernetes needed were not accessible.

As a workaround, I found the "iptables-persistent" package and saved my rules permanently in Ubuntu using the command **"sudo su "/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"**.

After this solution I applied, when I rebooted the server, my rules were now permanently effective.